Why is using "affecting" in "There will be a huge storm "affecting" our areas during this week" correct?
I'm so confused about why this is correct. Is it because "affecting" is considered a gerund? Or is it because it is in the continuous tense?

Would the present tense version also confuse you? There is a huge storm affecting our areas this week. What about without the "there" part? A huge storm is affecting our areas this week.

Yes, because "is" should be with There is but affecting should have its v.to be as a continuous tense isn't it? Also shouldn't be "There is a huge storm which affects our areas this week." is the correct present tense version?

Then I fear you also won't like this sentence: Somebody came to the door asking for you while you were away. I wonder whether what you're struggling with is actually whiz-deletion. I know we have a bunch of questions from learners who are confused by this; let me see whether I can't find you some of those.

Thank you for your answer, this is the first time I heard "whiz-deletion" and I'm looking at this top too.

Could you please try looking through those five duplicates that I've marked here to see whether these help your understanding of this type of construction?

'A huge storm will be affecting our area/s this week' is fairly obviously grammatical, but sounds somehow weak without context, slightly clumsy. Using existential there  complicates the grammar but adds polish.

@tchrist from what I briefly read through the duplicate posts the answer should be either Participle clauses or Whiz-Deletion. I think I have to take more time and research to fully understand these topics. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.

We don't say "There is a huge storm which affects our area this week" because we use the plain present tense for habitual actions, and continuous present for actions that aren't habitual. For example, we say "I am going to the store today, but I go to the store every day. Maybe see this question.

It's the continuous tense. The storm will be affecting (having an effect on) our area for all of this week.
Or you could see it as a participle, functioning as an adjective describing the storm.

So, is "be" both for "There will be"(as There is/are) and also an auxiliary verb for continuous tense?

@ まいにちフライデー The default analysis, I'd say, is that the relevant verb string is 'will be affecting' with 'will be' auxiliary and 'affecting' the present participle (ie verbal). The adjectival interpretation of 'affecting' with 'be' copular ('will' still auxiliary) is discounted by say CGEL as there is a direct object, 'our areas'. For truly ambiguous examples, consider 'The window was broken.' / 'John is tiring.' [note the different interpretations]
